# request.getParameter() returning null values in servlet...dont know whats wrong

Tags: java, servlets

This is the html form from where i"m sending the data through input form....

```
<form role="form" action = "AddServlet" method="GET">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class= "bg-primary">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter name of the book">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="author" class= "bg-primary">Author</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" placeholder="Enter the authors name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="count" class= "bg-primary">Count</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="count" placeholder="Enter the number of books">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description" class= "bg-primary">Description</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="description" placeholder="Enter book description"></textarea>
  </div> 

  <input type="submit" value = "submit">
</form>
```

and this is the servlet where I'm recieving the data through request.getParameter....

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import org.hibernate.Transaction;  
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;  

@WebServlet("/AddServlet")
public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


   String name, author, description, count;



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

         Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file  

            //creating seession factory object  
            SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  

            //creating session object  
            Session session=factory.openSession();  

            //creating transaction object  
            Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  

            Books b = new Books();  

            name = request.getParameter("name");
            author = request.getParameter("author");
            description = request.getParameter("description");

            count = request.getParameter("count");


            System.out.println(count + "dfghjkls");  
            b.setName(name);  
            b.setAuthor(author);  
            b.setDescription(description);
            b.setCount(count);

            session.persist(b);//persisting the object  

            t.commit();//transaction is commited  
            session.close();  

            System.out.println("successfully saved");  


    }

}
```

but this is returning null values...dont know whats going wrong with this...

Comment: please try without creating a new session and transaction first - just to check if the new session overwrites the original one.

Comment: What is returning `null` values? The request contains data you enter on the html form.

Comment: Have u created setName(name),setAuthor(author) in ur class Book ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer...label for= "name" was the problem....removed it..
perhaps "for = " was creating ambiguity and so browser couldnt collect data